# Problema al cargar tabla dentro de cards html, mysql, php

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

Estoy intentando cargar informacion de una card en base al id de esta misma.

Tablas de donde muestro la informacion:

```
create table reporteCambios(
    id_repcambio int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
    id int not null,
    id_client int not null,
    mes_reporte varchar(100) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY(id_repcambio),
    INDEX(id), FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES users(id)
);

create table Cambiosxmeses(
    id_cambio int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
    id_repcambio int not null,
    id int not null,
    id_client int not null,
    nombre_cambio varchar(100) not null,
    descripcion_cambio varchar(500) not null,
    fecha_cambio date,
    idcambio varchar(50) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY(id_cambio),
    INDEX(id_repcambio),FOREIGN KEY(id_repcambio) REFERENCES reporteCambios(id_repcambio)
);


    <div class="content">
        <!-- # Row -->
        <div class="row">
            <!-- # render card MESES -->
            <?php
                $userid=$_SESSION['user_id'];//Obtengo el id del usuario para saber cuales cards voy a cargar en base a reporteCambios y Cambiosxmeses
                $sql = "SELECT c.id_client, c.name_client, us.email, rep.id_repcambio, rep.mes_reporte
                FROM clients as c
                INNER JOIN users as us
                ON c.id_client = us.id_client
                INNER JOIN reporteCambios as rep 
                ON rep.id = us.id
                WHERE us.id=$userid";
                if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
                if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){  
                         $idMes=$row['id_repcambio']; //obtengo el id del card para cargar la informacion correspondiente dentro de Cambiosxmeses
                ?>
            <!-- /# Col-6 -->
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header cambiosHeader">
                        <!-- Titulo del card -->
                        <h4><?php echo $row['mes_reporte'];?></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="custom-tab">
                            <nav>
                                <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
                                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="<?php echo $row['idcambio'];?>-tab"
                                        data-toggle="tab" href="#<?php echo $row['idcambio'];?>" role="tab"
                                        aria-controls="<?php echo $row['idcambio'];?>" aria-selected="true">Tab #1
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </nav>
                            <!-- Aqui voy a cargar el contenido de cada una de las tabs generadas en <nav>... copiado en Media-Queries -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /# Col-6 -->
            <?php
                }
                mysqli_free_result($result);
                } else{
                echo "No se encontró ninguna card.";
                }
                } else{
                echo "$sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
                }
                ?>
            <!-- /# render card MESES -->
        </div> <!-- /# Row -->
    </div><!-- .content -->
```

El codigo anterior me genera sin problema los cards para los 4 meses agregados en la tabla **reporteCambios**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema yace cuando quiero cargarle las tabs internas a cada una de las cards, para empezar le especifico que me cargue unicamente, de las 4 cards, las que tengan tabs agregadas mediante la consulta:

```
SELECT reporteCambios.id_repcambio, Cambiosxmeses.nombre_cambio, Cambiosxmeses.idcambio 
FROM reporteCambios JOIN Cambiosxmeses ON reporteCambios.id_repcambio=Cambiosxmeses.id_repcambio
WHERE reporteCambios.id_repcambio=$idMes;
```

Y seguido cargo la tab en base al id de cada una de las cards con la consulta sencilla:

```
SELECT id_repcambio, nombre_cambio, idcambio 
FROM Cambiosxmeses 
WHERE id_repcambio=$mesActivo;
```

Lo que pasa es que me carga bien toda la informacion pero solo me carga una Card, solo me carga el mes de Enero y deberia cargarme el mes de Enero y Febrero, que son las cards que tienen tabs.

Como si el while cargase bien el id 1, pero no avanzara al id 2.

Muestro el codigo despues de los cambios:

```
<div class="content">
    <!-- # Row -->
    <div class="row">
        <!-- # render card MESES -->
        <?php
            $userid=$_SESSION['user_id']; //Obtengo el id del usuario para saber cuales cards voy a cargar en base a reporteCambios y Cambiosxmeses
            $sql = "SELECT c.id_client, c.name_client, us.email, rep.id_repcambio, rep.mes_reporte
            FROM clients as c
            INNER JOIN users as us
            ON c.id_client = us.id_client
            INNER JOIN reporteCambios as rep 
            ON rep.id = us.id
            WHERE us.id=$userid";
            if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){  
                     $idMes=$row['id_repcambio']; //obtengo el id del card para cargar la informacion correspondiente dentro de Cambiosxmeses
            ?>
        <!-- /# Col-6 -->
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header cambiosHeader">
                    <!-- Titulo del card -->
                    <h4><?php echo $row['mes_reporte'];?></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="custom-tab">
                        <nav>

                            <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">

                            <?php
                            $sql = "SELECT reporteCambios.id_repcambio, Cambiosxmeses.nombre_cambio, Cambiosxmeses.idcambio 
                            FROM reporteCambios JOIN Cambiosxmeses ON reporteCambios.id_repcambio=Cambiosxmeses.id_repcambio
                            WHERE reporteCambios.id_repcambio=$idMes";
                            if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
                            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){  
                                    $mesActivo=$row['id_repcambio']; //Voy a mostrar unicamente las cards que tengan tabs y obtengo los ID 
                            ?>

                            <?php
                            $sql = "SELECT id_repcambio, nombre_cambio, idcambio FROM Cambiosxmeses WHERE id_repcambio=$mesActivo";  //Obtengo la informacion de cada una de las cards para crear las cards
                            if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
                            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){  
                            ?>
                                <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="<?php echo $row['idcambio'];?>-tab"
                                    data-toggle="tab" href="#<?php echo $row['idcambio'];?>" role="tab"
                                    aria-controls="<?php echo $row['idcambio'];?>" aria-selected="true"><?php echo $row['nombre_cambio'];?>
                                </a>

                                <?php
                            }
                            mysqli_free_result($result);
                            } else{
                            echo "No se encontró ninguna card.";
                            }
                            } else{
                            echo "$sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
                            }
                            ?>
                            
                            <?php
                            }
                            mysqli_free_result($result);
                            } else{
                            echo "No se encontró ninguna card.";
                            }
                            } else{
                            echo "$sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
                            }
                            ?>
                            </div>
                        </nav>
                        <!-- Aqui voy a cargar el contenido de cada una de las tabs generadas en <nav>... copiado en Media-Queries -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /# Col-6 -->
        <?php
            }
            mysqli_free_result($result);
            } else{
            echo "No se encontró ninguna card.";
            }
            } else{
            echo "$sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
            }
            ?>
        <!-- /# render card MESES -->
    </div> <!-- /# Row -->
</div><!-- .content -->
```

The result:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estaria muy agradecido si alguien me ayuda a entender el porque sucede esto.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas pisando la variable `$result` y es por esa razón que no podes continuar iterando correctamente los meses para generar los `cards`.

Solo tenes que cambiar el nombre de la variable en las consultas para generar los `tabs`.

#### Ejemplo:

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT reporteCambios.id_repcambio, Cambiosxmeses.nombre_cambio, Cambiosxmeses.idcambio 
       FROM reporteCambios JOIN Cambiosxmeses ON reporteCambios.id_repcambio=Cambiosxmeses.id_repcambio
       WHERE reporteCambios.id_repcambio=$idMes";

// ACA - Cambiamos el nombre de la variable
if($result2 = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){  

            $mesActivo=$row['id_repcambio']; //Voy a mostrar unicamente las cards que tengan tabs y obtengo los ID

            $sql = "SELECT id_repcambio, nombre_cambio, idcambio FROM Cambiosxmeses WHERE id_repcambio=$mesActivo";  //Obtengo la informacion de cada una de las cards para crear las cards

            // ACA - Cambiamos el nombre de la variable
            if($result3 = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
                if(mysqli_num_rows($result3) > 0) {
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)){

                    // resto del código
```

**PD**: No te olvides de corregir el nombre de las variables en los `mysqli_free_result($result);`

Comment: Hola @Marcos, muchas gracias; no me estaba dando cuenta y tampoco me puse hacer un var_dump para comprobar esta variable, ya se ha solucionado. Gracias nuevamente.