# Evitar repetir líneas de tabla html sobre un tabla de mysql en php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Intento hacer un código en donde pueda crear una tabla en html de forma que automáticamente cree líneas de la tabla hasta el final del campo. Lo he intentado con un for pero no hay forma

````
          <caption>GASTOS POR CATEGORIAS</caption>
            <tbody>
            <?php 
                $query = "select * from viaje WHERE viaje_nombre= '".$Reg."'";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);                 
            
            
                while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
                    $tipo = $row['tipo'];
                
                ?>
              <tr>
                <th><?php $tipo ?></th>
                <!-- TOTAL -->
             <td><?php $query="SELECT CONCAT(SUM(cantidad), ' €') '".$tipo."' FROM viaje WHERE tipo = '".$tipo."' and viaje_nombre= '".$Reg."'";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
                
            //Si no hay gasto poner '0 €'
            if (!empty($tipo)){
                 echo $tipo; ?></td>
            <?php } else {
                echo '0 €';  ?></td>
            <?php } ?>
             </tr>
            <?php } //FIN FOR ?>
                
              </tbody>            

      </table>```
````

Comment: Estas usando MVC ? SI es asi, yo te aconsejaria traer a la vista un array ya customizado con la fomra que quieras tener para tu tabla, asi solo tienes que recorrer un array cargado previamente, ganas en legibilidad, mantenimiento y optimizacion

Comment: Estas pisando la variable `$result` y es por esta razón que no podes iterar correctamente la primer consulta.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Problema al cargar tabla dentro de cards html, mysql, php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/430519/problema-al-cargar-tabla-dentro-de-cards-html-mysql-php)

Answer (score 0):

Este es el código final realizando modificaciones. Es cierto que contenía codigo innecesario, pero el resultado me lo estaba dando. El problema lo tenía en el for que no pasaba del primer valor del array.

```
<div id="categorias">
      <table>
      <caption>GASTOS POR CATEGORIAS</caption>
        <tbody>
        <?php
            $query = "select DISTINCTROW tipo from viaje WHERE viaje_nombre= '".$Reg."'";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
            //$row=$result->fetch_assoc();
            $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            //Bucle for para rellenar a array @valoresTipo
            for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
                $valorTipo = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                $valoresTipo[$i] = $valorTipo["tipo"];

            }
            ?>

                 <tr>
                <?php for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) { ?>
                    <th><?php

                    echo $valoresTipo[$i]; ?></th>
                 <td><?php $query="SELECT CONCAT(SUM(cantidad), ' €') '".$valoresTipo[$i]."' FROM viaje WHERE tipo = '".$valoresTipo[$i]."' and viaje_nombre= '".$Reg."'";
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
                    $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                    //Si no hay gasto poner '0 €'
                    if (!empty($row[$valoresTipo[$i]])){
                        echo $row[$valoresTipo[$i]]; ?></td>
                <?php } else {
                        echo '0 €';  ?></td>
                <?php } ?>
                 </tr>
        <?php } //FIN FOR ?>

          </tbody>

  </table>
```